# debug access token using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

i want to know when the access token will expire

i am using httprequest and getting response from the request that contain the link:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=ACCESS_TOKEN

and searching for the word `Expires` and trying to read the string between parenthesis which contain (in about x minutes)

but getting error that logged out can any one help me please ?

```
string site = "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=";
string token = "";
getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site + token);
string result;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
{
result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.Contains("Expires"));
```

i am getting false i need to have a result that contain the string "Expires" and read the time that will expire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/

Make a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

**input_token**: the Access Token to debug

**access_token**: your App Access Token or a valid User Access Token from a developer of the app.

If you are using the FB C# SDK (http://csharpsdk.org/)

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("app_access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("debug_token", new { input_token = "access_token_to_debug" });
var appId = result.data.app_id;
var isValid = result.data.is_valid;
var application = result.data.application;
var userId = result.data.user_id;
var expiresAt = result.data.expires_at;
var scopes = result.data.scopes;
```

You can learn how to get the app access token at http://csharpsdk.org/docs/faq I also updated the docs to include debugging the access token.

Note: When you get the access token from the user make sure to store the expiry dates too, so you can avoid this call.